# google sheets query date only brings one row result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a tab call (Data Import) where I have the whole raw data imported in google sheets, in the next tab I have my query that looks as below;

This is the query -> `=QUERY('Data Import'!$I1:$O, A1, 1)`

A1 is equal to -> `="SELECT K, O, J WHERE J >= "&F1&""`

F1 is equal to -> `44196`

The result I get is only the first row, but I want all the rows that contains the same date which are a total 25 plus the header with the column names.

Does anyone figures what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in A1:

```
=QUERY('Data Import'!I1:O, 
 "SELECT K,O,J WHERE J >= "&F1*1, 1)
```

you could also solve it like:

```
=QUERY('Data Import'!I1:O, 
 "SELECT K,O,J WHERE J >= date '"&TEXT(F1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for support, I really appreciate it, still couldn't make it work

Comment: @AurelioMartín can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: The second option provided in your comment works, really.

Comment: The date sorting now works just fine, thanks!

```=QUERY('Data Import'!I1:O, 
 "SELECT K,O,J WHERE J >= date '"&TEXT(F2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND J <= date '"&TEXT(F3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 1)```

Comment: As a brief summary of the functions used in this formula I would like to add that [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) will convert any number into a text in a specified format (in this case date format) therefore solving the incompatibility of the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) language (as it must use strings and not numbers).